# Add text from a file b/w two specific line numbers using linux (sed,awk)?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, cat

I have specific lines numbers from a file and want to insert content of another file b/w those two line numbers

For e.g-

File to be inserted

```
$ cat insert.txt

1
2
3
```

in the following file

```
$cat File.txt
a
b
c
d
e
```

How can I insert content of file insert.txt b/w line no 3 and 4 of File.txt? 
Output:

```
a
b
c
1
2
3
d
e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed with an address `3` (the third line) and the command `r` for reading a file:

```
sed '3 r insert.txt' File.txt
```